# How can I refresh a fragment list from an action bar button with RSS Feed information?

Tags: android

I'm doing my first app, a RSS Feed application, for learning the multiple technologies associated, like xml, parsing, connecting to the internet, getting the information, processing it, etc.

I've decided to use the newest Android elements, such as the Action Bar and Fragments. So I've done an action bar with a few options, like Refresh (which refreshes the RSS list), Preferences, About and Exit. The main issue is with the Refresh.

I'm pressing Refresh and the option creates an object which will get the XML, which should return the information for the newsList Fragment. But I can't pass the information to the fragment, but I also can't Toast the xml information to the screen, so I cannot test if I'm getting everything correctly.

My programming background is not in Java, I'm used to Web Developing (PHP) and scripting (Shell) so I guess I'm missing some basic stuff, which I apologize in advance.

Can anybody at least give me some hints, in order for me to know what to search and get back in the right path?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, can you please try to emphasize what your exact question is? I'm reading this but having a hard time understand what you're asking. What do you mean you "can't" pass the information? Why not?

Comment: It's a little bit hard to explain... I'm going to try anyway.
I have an Action Bar, with Tabs and a few buttons in the ICS menu button. I also have four fragments, which already open if I click the corresponding tab in the action bar.
What I can't do is click Refresh Button in the Action Bar, which using AsyncTask, will try to get the RSS Feed information and fill in the List in the fragment (first, for testing, I'm trying to Toast it to screen). I'm thinking of passing the information to a database and refresh the list afterwards, but I'm not being able of using the first part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the class that handles the downloading/parsing of the RSS feed, but you don't know how to pass the processed feed-info back to the ListFragment right?

There're multiple ways to solve this. You could use the [callback](http://sanjib-swain.blogspot.com/2009/05/implementing-callback-pattern-in-java.html) pattern for your rss-retrieving class for example. So the Activity starts off this rss-retrieving object asynchronously, and registers itself as a listener of this object. When the rss-stuff is done, the object notifies your Activity about this through the listener-interface.

In response, the Activity can get a reference for the ListFragment (using the FragmentManager) and call a method on it that refreshes the list, passing in the parsed RSS-info as a parameter.

Comment: Exactly. I have a Main Class, in which I implement the Action Bar and create the fragment objects, from each Fragment. In each fragment I inflate each layout oncreateview.
If I press Refresh, onOptionsItemSelected I call an AsyncTask in the Main Class, which calls the rss feed, using SAXParserFactory, SAXParser, XMLReader and a RSS Handler.
I was trying to use the AsyncTask to refresh directly the feeds, as it was asked by the user. So I guess the callback is not the best option. Or am I wrong?
Thanks for everything :)